# why is bitcoin-qt connecting to port 9051?

Tags: client

Running bitcoin-qt with default policy in the OUTPUT chain to DROP I see lots of packets from localhost to localhost with destination port 9051 being dropped. If I open that port the node syncs. I do not see any service listening on that port. Why is it connecting? This is a tor port and I am not currently running tor here.

Comment: 9051 is usually a Tor transport controller port. Bitcoin might just be looking to see if it can connect to the network via tor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing probes for automatic configuration if it were running.